# Open PDF-file with PHP

Tags: php

How do I open a PDF-file with PHP, that is not accessible via the web browser? What I mean is, that you can't open the PDF-file by typing the location to the PDF in the web browser.

How do I open the file with PHP?

I've have the following code here:

```
$kollinr = $this->findFreeKollinr($link);
        $send_id = $link->inQuery("INSERT INTO frakthandling (abonnemang_id, ref, weight, content, kollinr, users_id, datum) VALUES(".$abonnemang_id.", '".$ref."', '".$weight."', '".$content."', '".$kollinr."', ".$user.", NOW())");
        if($abonnemang_id==99999999)
        {
            $link->inQuery("INSERT INTO frakthandling_dyn (frakthandling_id, fromname, fromaddr, fromort, fromtele, toname, toaddr, toort, tozip) VALUES(".$send_id.", '".$dyndata["fromname"]."', '".$dyndata["fromaddr"]."', '".$dyndata["frompostnr"]." ".$dyndata["fromort"]."', '".$dyndata["fromtele"]."', '".$dyndata["toname"]."', '".$dyndata["toaddr"]."', '".$dyndata["topostnr"]." ".$dyndata["toort"]."', '".$dyndata["topostnr"]."')");
        }

        $file = file_get_contents("http://x.x.x.x/documents/multifrakt.php?id=".$send_id."");
        $retdata = array();
        $retstatus=0;
        //echo $file;
        $local_filename  = "/data/web/frakt/frakt_".$send_id.".pdf";
        //$remote_filename = "frakt_".$send_id.".pdf";
        $local_filename_ps  = "/data/web/frakt/frakt_".$send_id.".ps";
        $remote_filename_ps = "frakt_".$send_id.".ps";
        $remote_filename_pdf = "frakt_".$send_id.".pdf";
        $dnfile = fopen($local_filename, "w");
        if(fwrite($dnfile, $file) === FALSE) {
           echo "Cannot write to file ($local_filename)";
           exit;
        }
    return $local_filename; //What should I return in order to open the file??
        fclose($dnfile);
```

The code above is a part of a class, which is instantiated when the code below is run:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['do_download']))
{
    $pdff = new frakt();
    $pdf_d = $pdff->downloadPDF($_POST["ref"], $_POST["weight"], $_POST["content"], 99999999, $_POST, $_SESSION["user"]["users_id"], $link);
    if($pdf_d) {    
        //Show the PDF here
    }
}
```

Anyone who can help me? :)

Comment: "What I mean is, that you can't open the PDF-file by typing the location to the PDF in the web browser" What do you mean by that? Is the file there or not? Is the server protected?

Comment: You cant view navigate to the pdf-filen in the web browser, so I guess the server is protected in some how.

Comment: How do you know it's there when you can not see it? Is it your server?

Comment: Because I can navigate to the file via my FTP-client. The file is written to the location /data/web/frakt/

Comment: Sorry, but in the end it is unclear what you ask. It _appears_ that you do not really yet understand how the components work together. So what you actually want to do. Please try to explain more clearly what your goal is in this. A browser by itself simply is not able to "open a PDF file". Either it can download it for you, or you need a browser plugin (comes down to a download too) or you need a client side scripting logic to interpret such a proprietary file format.

Comment: you can check for the chmod of the files. when the directory is public and you are ok with having the files exposed to the public the permissions are one thing that prevent files from beeing reached. arkascha is absolutely right.

Comment: I don't know how I can explain more.

When you type in the location to the PDF in the web browser like this: http://x.x.x.x/data/web/kundadmin_dev/www/frakt/frakt_14401.pdf

I get this: The requested URL /data/web/kundadmin_dev/www/frakt/frakt_14401.pdf was not found on this server.

So the folder cant be accessed via the web browser.

Comment: My goals is that when you hit a button, Download PDF, I want to download a pdf-file that is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has an internal file path on the server. This is only visible inside the server (and to ftp if you log in)
This is "x.x.x.x/data/web/kundadmin_dev/www/frakt/frakt_14401.pdf"

The webserver has a document root. This is the start point for the web server, and only document inside it are visible.
It is probably "/data/web/kundadmin_dev/www"
(maybe "/data/web/kundadmin_dev/www/frakt", you need to check yourself)

The need to translate between the two pathes.

So you can download your file by putting this in the url in the browser
x.x.x.x/frakt/frakt_14401.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code which is doing the downloading for you, looks like the actual file name aand location are hidden from the user. The scripts basically makes an post request. What i would recommend here, is to do the same with curl. SO basically,
1) Put exit in action page, and print the post object.
2) Remove the exit, and pass the post argumets to a curl post request via command line.